# Can I download Ubuntu 15.10 drivers (amd) and will work on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: drivers, amd-processor

When I try searching for my drivers I get this:
http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Ubuntu%20x86%2064

will 14.10 Ubuntu drivers work on ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, they will not.**

In fact, you won't get any GUI at all (if you do, it will be in Low Graphics Mode) until you uninstall the drivers.

AMD is supposedly working a new driver for 16.04 that's called amdgpu. Until that comes out, however, 16.04 is stuck with open source drivers for AMD cards, unless you're willing to try out the beta:

http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=amd-gpu-pro&num=1

I recommend that you stay with open source or downgrade until the driver is stable, but you can always try it.

Comment: Would you mind clicking that checkmark under the arrows on my answer? It'll mark it as accepted, and will let others know that the question is solved.